# Get previous versions of a package in NPM

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-3

How do I find out all previous versions of a package using npm?

In this instance, I am interested in cordova. If I execute `npm install -g cordova`, I will install the latest version (which is what you'd expect).

If I do `npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0` then I get the specific version installed - I would like to know because I am having troubles with the latest version of a package, and would like to test which version the problem occurred in - but cannot do that if I don't know which npm package versions there have been.

Comment: If I already install the latest version of cordova, and then i now wanted to install the specific older version... should I remove the latest version first? how to do that @keldar?

Comment: I'd recommend it - try `npm uninstall -g cordova`. That doesn't always remove every directory, you'll also want to delete `~/.cordova` - where `~` is your home directory (which, on Windows 7+ is `C:\Users\<username>`).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Try:

**In your terminal:**

```
npm view cordova versions
```

**Output:**

```
[ '0.0.0-fake',
  '0.0.1',
  '0.0.2',
  '0.0.3',
  '0.0.4',
  '0.0.5',
  '0.0.6',
  '0.0.7',
  '0.0.8',
  '0.0.9',
  '0.1.0',
  '0.1.1',
  '0.1.2',
  '0.1.3',
  '0.1.4',
  '0.1.5',
  '0.1.6',
  '0.1.7',
  '0.1.8',
  '0.1.9',
  '0.1.10',
  '0.1.11',
  '0.1.12',
  '0.1.13',
  '0.1.14',
  '2.2.0',
  '2.3.0',
  '2.3.1',
  '2.3.2',
  '2.3.3',
  '2.3.5',
  '2.3.6',
  '2.4.0',
  '2.4.1',
  '2.4.2',
  '2.4.3',
  '2.4.4',
  '2.4.5',
  '2.4.6',
  '2.4.7',
  '2.4.8',
  '2.4.9',
  '2.4.10',
  '2.5.0',
  '2.5.2',
  '2.5.3',
  '2.5.4',
  '2.5.5',
  '2.6.0',
  '2.6.1',
  '2.6.2',
  '2.7.0-rc.1',
  '2.7.1-rc.1',
  '2.7.2',
  '2.7.3',
  '2.7.4',
  '2.8.0',
  '2.8.1',
  '2.8.2',
  '2.8.3',
  '2.8.4',
  '2.8.5',
  '2.8.6',
  '2.8.7',
  '2.8.8',
  '2.8.9',
  '2.8.10',
  '2.8.11',
  '2.8.12',
  '2.8.13',
  '2.8.14',
  '2.8.15',
  '2.8.16',
  '2.8.17',
  '2.8.18',
  '2.8.19',
  '2.8.20',
  '2.8.21',
  '2.8.22',
  '2.8.23',
  '2.8.24',
  '2.8.25',
  '2.9.0-rc1',
  '2.9.0',
  '2.9.1',
  '2.9.2',
  '2.9.3',
  '2.9.4',
  '2.9.5',
  '2.9.6',
  '2.9.7',
  '3.0.0-rc1',
  '3.0.0-rc1-1',
  '3.0.0-rc1-3',
  '3.0.0',
  '3.0.1',
  '3.0.2',
  '3.0.3',
  '3.0.4',
  '3.0.5',
  '3.0.6',
  '3.0.7',
  '3.0.8',
  '3.0.9',
  '3.0.10',
  '3.1.0-0.1.0',
  '3.1.0-0.2.0',
  '3.2.0-0.1.0',
  '3.2.0-0.2.0',
  '3.2.0-0.3.0',
  '3.2.0-0.4.0',
  '3.2.0-rc.1',
  '3.3.0-0.1.1',
  '3.3.0-rc.1',
  '3.3.1-0.1.2',
  '3.3.1-0.3.0',
  '3.3.1-0.3.1',
  '3.3.1-0.4.1',
  '3.3.1-0.4.2',
  '3.4.0-0.1.0',
  '3.4.0-0.1.1',
  '3.4.0-0.1.2',
  '3.4.0-0.1.3',
  '3.4.1-0.1.0',
  '3.5.0-0.2.0',
  '3.5.0-0.2.1',
  '3.5.0-0.2.2',
  '3.5.0-0.2.3',
  '3.5.0-0.2.4',
  '3.5.0-0.2.6',
  '3.5.0-0.2.7',
  '3.6.0-0.2.8',
  '3.6.0-0.2.9',
  '3.6.1-0.2.10',
  '3.6.3-0.2.11',
  '3.6.3-0.2.12',
  '3.6.3-0.2.13',
  '4.0.0',
  '4.0.1',
  '4.1.0',
  '4.1.1',
  '4.1.2',
  '4.1.3-nightly.2014.10.21',
  '4.2.0',
  '4.3.0',
  '4.3.1',
  '5.0.0',
  '5.1.1',
  '5.2.0',
  '5.3.1',
  '5.3.3',
  '5.4.0' ]
```

That should list the old versions of the package you're looking for -- in this case, the package is "cordova."

Then you can install what you want using whichever npm install command you choose to install with.

Comment: No problem. You should check out the list of commands npm has to offer right out of the box. The list will come in handy. Oh, and if this is the answer, you should accept it so that someone knows the answer when they encounter the same question! @keldar

Comment: Done - and I'll take your advice on board and take a look. Thanks again :)

Comment: Great post. I assume I can simply install an older version without uninstalling the newer one, vote up if correct, thanks.

Comment: If anyone gets truncated list - use `--json` parameter. List then will be complete without any truncations.

Answer (score 28):

To get a list of all versions available:

```
npm view cordova versions
```

to install an older version:

```
npm install -g cordova@5.2.0
```

Answer (score 11):

In your CLI type `npm view cordova versions`, this would show you all the versions of cordova. Then type `npm -g install cordova@versionno`. For example, if u want to install version  5.0.0, type `npm install -g cordova@5.0.0`