# How to install particular Angular version using node package manager

Tags: npm, angular-cli

How can install a specific version of Angular 4 using node package manager?
I ran `npm view @angular/cli versions` command , the available version displayed are

I could not see version 4 and 5 in the list
how could i download the version 4 or 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get previous versions of a package in NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314132/get-previous-versions-of-a-package-in-npm)

Comment: My issue is totally different from the issue @Vlad274

Comment: There is no version 4 or 5 of `@angular/cli`. Prior to the v6 release the version numbers were out of sync. Some brief research recommends cli version `1.4.10` for Angular 4 and `1.7.4` for Angular 5. YMMV as these are old packages and may have bugs that were addressed in later release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install this specific version of the angular cli you have to use this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9
```

Perhaps you have an other version currently installed on your system you should read [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-downgrade-Angular-Version-version-5-to-version-2) also.

source: [Angular downgrade from version 5 to 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186038/angular-downgrade-from-version-5-to-4?utm_campaign=google_rich_qa&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I ran `npm view @angular/cli versions` command, its does not displays version 4 and 5

Comment: please run `ng -v` and see whats Angular CLI version

Comment: I tried `npm install -g @angular/cli` and it downloaded the latest version of angular cli and angular

Comment: how about running `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9` instead!

Answer (score 1):

To install a particular version you need to run the following command line

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@<version>
```

Example:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0
```

You can see the available versions with the following command:

```
npm view @angular/cli
```

Comment: npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@4.0.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.