# Why do I get this when running Cordova commands? "Unhandled 'error' event. (Parsing [...]/config.xml failed)"

Tags: cordova

I was using these commands:

```
$ cordova build ios --release
$ cordova platform rm ios
$ cordova platform rm ios --save
$ cordova platform version
$ cordova platform list
$ cordova platform ls
cordova platform ?
```

All of these commands generated the same error:

```
Unhandled "error" event. (Parsing /Users/Steve/Documents/APPS/Sheets/sheets83/config.xml failed)
```

Path above exists, so that's not the error. Reviewing my config.xml doesn't show any apparent formatting errors. SublimeText doesn't flag any offending lines with warning symbols. I've been making Cordova apps for years.

More info with --verbose (does this help narrow it down?):

```
$ cordova platform ls --verbose
Unhandled "error" event. (Parsing /Users/Steve/Documents/APPS/Sheets/sheets83/config.xml failed)
Error: Unhandled "error" event. (Parsing /Users/Steve/Documents/APPS/Sheets/sheets83/config.xml failed)
    at CordovaEventEmitter.emit (events.js:186:19)
    at CordovaEventEmitter.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/events.js:69:22)
    at new ConfigParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigParser/ConfigParser.js:34:16)
    at getScriptsFromConfigXml (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:107:21)
    at getApplicationHookScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:56:17)
    at Object.getHookScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:40:16)
    at HooksRunner.fire (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:56:33)
    at Function.list (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform/list.js:26:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform/index.js:81:35
    at <anonymous>
```

These commands did not generate the above error:

```
$ cordova info
$ cordova help
```

Possible fix ideas? Error appears to be consistent when using "cordova platform" commands. Seems to be a problem with Node modules.

**Environment as of 7/2019**

*About this Mac:*

OS High Sierra 10.13.6

iMac (Mid 2011)

*cordova -v*

```
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

*cordova platform ?*

```
"cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
```

*cordova plugin list*

```
"plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}
    }
```

Xcode 10.1

SublimeText v3.2.1 Build 3207

Comment: Error message persists in spite of: reinstalling homebrew, brew install yarn to replace bower, npm install -g npm, npm install -g cordova. Unbelievable.

Comment: Is there a reason why there are no answers?

Comment: Today I'm gettings the same exactly error...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working on an older project built with cordova `7.0.0`, but my Mac was running cordova `9.0.0`.

[Downgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314132/get-previous-versions-of-a-package-in-npm) cordova solved the `config.xml` parsing issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the config.xml is an auto generated file check if you have it open and by mistake you edit it. Then will be unable to parse the file.

Close the file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found after validating my config.xml with https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ that I have extra spaces at the end of the file after deleting the extra spaces my Cordova commands back to work normally.