# In NPM, How to get the list of packages under a scope?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

We are developing custom packages and each package is maintained under the scope. For example:

1. `@nest/common`
2. `@nest/core`
3. `@nest/microservice`

How to get the list of packages available in the particular scope? For e.g I want to view the list of packages under `@nest`. `npm list` returns all the packages.

Comment: `npm search @nest`? Or if you mean you want to search installed packages in the current project with a prefix, then e.g. `npm list --depth 0 | grep @nest`.

Comment: Thanks. it's working. but its returning only the latest versions. Is there a way I can get all the versions published so far? Basically I want to see all the complete metadata information for each package

Comment: If you want to see old versions of a package, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314411/3001761. But it's unclear what problem you're actually trying to solve here, please [edit] to add that context.

Comment: Ok. I think I need to combine npm search, npm show and npm view to get what I wanted. Is there any package available for that?

Comment: If there is, it'll be available via https://www.npmjs.com/.

Answer (score 13):

npm uses the search api from [npms.io](https://npms.io) [[docs]](https://api-docs.npms.io/), which, includes the following:

> Besides normal text, q supports qualifiers to express filters and other modifiers:
>
> - `scope:types`: Show/filter results that belong to the `@types` scope

```bash
$ curl -s "https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:nest" | jq -r '.results[] | .package.name'
@nest/testing
@nest/core
@nest/microservices
@nest/websockets
```

```
» npm search scope:nest
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
@nest/testing             | Nest - the testing…  | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22 | 4.5.4    |
@nest/core                | Nest - the core…     | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22 | 4.5.4    |
@nest/microservices       | Nest - the…          | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22 | 4.5.4    |
@nest/websockets          | Nest - the…          | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22 | 4.5.4    |
```

*Updated 2022-10-03*

---

Original Answer:

Searching on npm for the explicit scope will return the available public packages for that scope.

For example:

```bash
» npm search @nest
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE
@nest/testing             | Nest - the testing…  | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22
@nest/core                | Nest - the core…     | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22
@nest/websockets          | Nest - the…          | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22
@nest/microservices       | Nest - the…          | =wbhob          | 2017-12-22
```

If the scope contains more than 20 packages, you need to use the `--searchlimit` option with a higher limit, like `npm --searchlimit=100 search @nestjs`

Comment: Is there an equivalent command for `yarn`?

Comment: @Casimir not for yarn 1.x, no. And i think you'd need a plugin for yarn2

Comment: To clarify, this does not work "as is" if your scope is on a private registry.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me and I got this error:
search must be called with arguments

Comment: @DinoSaadeh your shell may be null globbing (ie, expanding to nothing) the query - try `npm search '@nest'`

Comment: This doesn't seem to list everything. E.g. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40nestjs has 37 packages, but `npm search @nestjs` only display 20 results...

Comment: @EricHaynes this can be overcome with the `--searchlimit` option (unfortunately, it's not documented and i had to do a bit of digging to find it). I'm updating the answer to mention that.

Comment: Ah, that did it. You would think it would mention when it's a truncated list, or at least display that it defaults the `--searchlimit` to 20. Thanks!